# What is a good/best way to implement a long living service apart from main thread

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I'm implementing a payment terminal in a POS (point of sale) application for Android. I have gotten an SDK for communicating with the payment terminal through Bluetooth.

Application startup: Initialize the payment terminal, check connection.

Then i need to keep it alive througout the application lifecycle, to be able to check connection status, and start/cancel transaction.

The main issue here is, what is a good/best way to implement this.
I cannot have it in the main thread as i have experienced ANR when doing that.

I was thinking that i maybe should create a service that runs in another process.

I found this table which gave me some indication of what i can use, but i'm not sure anyway. The closest thing to use here was the IntentService, but i'm afraid that since i cannot run tasks in parallell with that, i won't be able to cancel a transaction while it's ongoing.
[Difference between Android Service,Thread,IntentService and AsyncTask](http://www.onsandroid.com/2011/12/difference-between-android.html)

Would a solution be a regular service which starts a thread when started?

A side note is that i need to be able to use the content provider to save transactional data as well.

What do you suggest?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a normal Service that owns a thread.  Send jobs to that thread to be executed in parallel on it.  Its a fairly common implementation pattern.

Comment: Seems fair enough, and one of the preffered solutions